# Grayscaled image has dark lower border

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv to take images using my webcam.

```
 cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 cv2.namedWindow("Handwritten Number Recognition")
 img_counter = 0

    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if not ret:
            print("failed to grab frame")
            break
        cv2.imshow("Handwritten Number Recognition", frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k%256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Prediction is underway...")
            break
        elif k%256 == 32:
            # SPACE pressed
            img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            print("Image taken!")
            img_counter += 1

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I then convert the image into grayscale and downsize it:

```
user_test = img_name
col = Image.open(user_test)
gray = col.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<100 else 255, '1')
bw.save("bw_image.jpg")
bw
img_array = cv2.imread("bw_image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_array = cv2.bitwise_not(img_array)
plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
img_size = 28
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))
final_array = new_array.reshape(1,-1)
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

But the images have a very dark patch in the bottom which hampers the predictions I want to make with my data:
[image]

Original image:
[image]

What can I do to get past this problem? Interestingly this only happens if I click the image using opencv. If I use an image clicked through the same webcam but through the camera appliucation the error is not visible (Adding path of the image for preprocessing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Choosing a better **global** threshold for the gray values. This is the easier less generic solution. Normally, people would choose the Otsu method to automatically select the optimal threshold. Have a look at: [Opencv Thresholding Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

   threshold, dst_img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
2. Using an **adaptive** threshold. Adaptive simply means using a calculated threshold for each sliding window location based on some criteria. Have a look at: [Niblack's Binarization methods](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga7b5b6f57106f4507d7195aef0fbe88d7)

Using option one:

```
img = cv2.imread("thresh.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
threshold, img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("thresh_bin.jpg", img)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Option 2 is the best choice for the input image provided. Clearly the lighting is uneven so adaptive threshold the best way. This link is the opencv tutorial on thresholding and it talks about the exact same issue you are facing @Arya https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: Thanks, but where in my code should I implement the threshold? I am getting various errors when I try.

Comment: @AryaMan I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

this problem because of used thresholding method

```
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<100 else 255, '1')
```

to solve this you can change the low limit value (100) to 75 or using opencv auto threshold

```
the, bw = cv2.threshold(gray_img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV using division normalization, thresholding and some morphology.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('five.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (555,555), 0)

# divide smooth by gray image
division = cv2.divide(smooth, gray, scale=255)

# invert
division = 255 - division

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(division, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# add white border to help morphology close
border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(thresh, 60,60,60,60, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255,255,255))
hh, ww = border.shape

# morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (29,29))
result = cv2.morphologyEx(border, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# remove border
result = result[60:hh-60, 60:ww-60]

# save results
cv2.imwrite('five_division_threshold.jpg',result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('smooth', smooth)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.imshow('result', result)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's a great piece of code! But it is not working as efficiently when I try to use it on other images. Are there any values in the code which I can replace with variables to make it more generalized?

Comment: What part is not working. The blur value can be different. The morphology kernel size can be different depending upon extraneous regions and the padding should be at least twice the size of the kernel. Probably an issue with the Otsu threshold. Replace that with a fixed threshold and an argument for the threshold value.

Comment: It's not able to filter out the number completely and a majority or sometimes the whole digit is left out (and the screen is completely white). Thanks,

Comment: Post an example that fails

Comment: I turned the OTSU threshold to some values which I found out using trial and error and it worked now! :)